# ASP.NET Core 6.0 Add Basket code not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I think something is missing in the code below. The code was working before, but I changed "ID" instead of "userName" and strangely it stopped working. I have examined many different codes, their structures are naturally similar to others but they insist on not working. "The product could not be added to the cart." I am getting the error in the Chrome console and log. I would be glad if you can help me.

I left the HTML and controller code below.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <form action="@Url.Action("addToBasket","Home")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="1" />
        <button type="button" onclick="submitData(@item.ProductId)" class="btn btn-dark">
            <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>Add Basket
        </button>
    </form>
}
<script>
    function submitData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("addToBasket", "Home")',
            data: { "id": $("#Id").val() }
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data.msg);
            });
    }
</script>

[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult addToBasket(int id)
{
    try
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userName = User.Identity.Name;
            var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName).Result;
            var product = cartItemRepository.GetById(id);

            if (user != null && product != null)
            {
                var cart = cartItemRepository.List(x => x.UserId == user.Id && x.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault();

                if (cart != null)
                {
                    cart.Quantity += 1;
                    cartItemManager.ItemUpdate(cart);
                }
                else
                {
                    var newCartItem = new CartItem
                        {
                            UserId = user.Id,
                            ProductId = id,
                            Quantity = 1,
                            ProductName = product.ProductName,
                            Price = product.Price,
                            Title = product.Title,
                        };
                    cartItemManager.ItemAdd(newCartItem);

                    // Return a successful response
                    return Json(new { status = true, msg = "Product added to cart." });
                }
            }
        }

        // Return JSON response on failure
        return Json(new { status = false, msg = "The product could not be added to the cart." });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the error message or get the error message
        var innerException = ex.InnerException;

        while (innerException != null)
        {
            var errorMessage = innerException.Message;

            // Logging or processing error message
            innerException = innerException.InnerException;
        }

        // In case of error, a more descriptive error message is terminated
        return Json(new { status = false, msg = "An error occurred while adding the product to the cart: " + ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of if conditions, you may want to simplify this logic.  It looks like the only time you return successfully is in your nested else block.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you say that the problem may be caused by "if" blocks, but when I separated the nested "if" blocks, the result did not change. @DevonBessemer

Comment: You have a problem with your html... You are creating a bunch of hidden fields with the Id="Id" but in html that is not valid.. Id attribute must have a unique value in the whole document. Then you use jquery to select by id ("#Id") which fails because there might be more than one in the document. You must use a unique id for each hidden field.

Comment: @jr.Dev I'm saying the if blocks make your code complex to reason about.  If you simplify this function, you may have an easier time debugging and finding what is failing.  You have a lot of paths through this code.

Answer (score 1):

Judging From your codes,you  always send  `{ "id": "1" }` to your backend

[image]

And it seems you got the error `"The product could not be added to the cart."`due to wrong ProductID

```
var newCartItem = new CartItem
                        {
                            UserId = user.Id,
                            //You assigned the wrong id to productId property here
                            ProductId = id,
                            Quantity = 1,
                            ProductName = product.ProductName,
                            Price = product.Price,
                            Title = product.Title,
                        };
                    cartItemManager.ItemAdd(newCartItem);
```

a minimal example to send the correct Id:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("addToBasket","Home")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="1" />
    <button type="button" onclick="submitData(this)" class="btn btn-dark">
        <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>
        Add Basket
    </button>
</form>

<form action="@Url.Action("addToBasket","Home")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="2" />
    <button type="button" onclick="submitData(this)" class="btn btn-dark">
        <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>
        Add Basket
    </button>
</form>

<script>
    
    var submitData = function (element) {
       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("addToBasket", "Home")',
            data: { "id": $(element).prev('input').val() }
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data.msg);
        });
    }
</script>
```

You could get the correct Id now:
[image]

Note:juding from your codes,you want to send ProductId back to your post endpoint,so
you should modify

```
<input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="1" />
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="@item.ProductId" />
```

Comment: I edited the code according to your suggestions and the ID looks correct. But the "product" variable, for which I left the breaking point, returns null. As you stated, "The product could not be added to the cart." I am encountering the error.

Comment: But the "product" variable, for which I left the breaking point, returns null----You get the product from repository by id:var product = cartItemRepository.GetById(id);   you have to check the codes related yourself  and compare to how did you get the product in GET request,if you still have problem,show us a minimal example